# Querying with cqlengine

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, object-object-mapping, cqlengine

I am trying to hook the [cqlengine CQL 3 object mapper](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine) with my web application running on CherryPy. Athough the [documentation](http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html) is very clear about querying, I am still not aware how to make queries on an existing table(and an existing keyspace) in my cassandra database. For instance I already have this table Movies containing the fields Title, rating, Year. I want to make the CQL query

```
SELECT * FROM Movies
```

How do I go ahead with the query after establishing the connection with

```
from cqlengine import connection
connection.setup(['127.0.0.1:9160'])
```

The `KEYSPACE` is called "TEST1".

Answer (score 6):

Abhiroop Sarkar,

I highly suggest that you read through all of the documentation at:

[**Current** Object Mapper Documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/object_mapper.html)

[**Legacy** CQLEngine Documentation](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

[Installation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html): `pip install cassandra-driver`

And take a look at this example project by the creator of CQLEngine, [rustyrazorblade](https://github.com/rustyrazorblade/):

[Example Project - Meat bot](https://github.com/rustyrazorblade/meatbot/)

Keep in mind, CQLEngine has been merged into the DataStax Cassandra-driver:

[Official Python Cassandra Driver Documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/index.html)

You'll want to do something like this:

**CQLEngine <= 0.21.0:**

```
from cqlengine.connection import setup


setup(['127.0.0.1'], 'keyspace_name', retry_connect=True)
```

If you need to create the keyspace still:

```
from cqlengine.management import create_keyspace


create_keyspace(
    'keyspace_name',
    replication_factor=1,
    strategy_class='SimpleStrategy'
)
```

**Setup your Cassandra Data Model**

You can do this in the same .py or in your models.py:

```
import datetime
import uuid

from cqlengine import columns, Model


class YourModel(Model):

    __key_space__ = 'keyspace_name'  # Not Required
    __table_name__ = 'columnfamily_name'  # Not Required

    some_int = columns.Integer(
        primary_key=True,
        partition_key=True
    )
    time = columns.TimeUUID(
        primary_key=True,
        clustering_order='DESC',
        default=uuid.uuid1,
    )
    some_uuid = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created = columns.DateTime(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    some_text = columns.Text(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.some_text

    def to_dict(self):
        data = {
            'text': self.some_text,
            'created': self.created,
            'some_int': self.some_int,
        }

        return data
```

**Sync your Cassandra ColumnFamilies**

```
from cqlengine.management import sync_table

from .models import YourModel


sync_table(YourModel)
```

Considering everything above, you can put all of the connection and syncing together, as many examples have outlined, say this is connection.py in our project:

```
from cqlengine.connection import setup
from cqlengine.management import sync_table

from .models import YourTable


def cass_connect():
    setup(['127.0.0.1'], 'keyspace_name', retry_connect=True)
    sync_table(YourTable)
```

**Actually Using the Model and Data**

```
from __future__ import print_function

from .connection import cass_connect
from .models import YourTable


def add_data():
    cass_connect()
    YourTable.create(
        some_int=5,
        some_text='Test0'
    )

    YourTable.create(
        some_int=6,
        some_text='Test1'
    )

    YourTable.create(
        some_int=5,
        some_text='Test2'
    )


def query_data():
    cass_connect()
    query = YourTable.objects.filter(some_int=5)
    # This will output each YourTable entry where some_int = 5
    for item in query:
        print(item)
```

Feel free to let ask for further clarification, if necessary.

Comment: Do I need to setup a connection everytime i need to interact with the database? is there no way to use an existing connection through an application?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to achieve this is to make model classes which mirror the schema of your existing cql tables, then run queries on them

Answer (score 1):

cqlengine is primarily an Object Mapper for Cassandra.  It does not interrogate an existing database in order to create objects for existing tables.  Rather it is usually intended to be used in the opposite direction (i.e. create tables from python classes).  If you want to query an existing table using cqlengine you will need to create python models that exactly correspond to your existing tables.

For example, if your current Movies table had 3 columns, id, title, and release_date you would need to create a cqlengine model that had those three columns.  Additionally, you would need to ensure that the **table_name** attribute on the class was exactly the same as the table name in the database.

```
from cqlengine import columns, Model

class Movie(Model):
    __table_name__ = "movies"
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    title = columns.Text()
    release_date = columns.Date()
```

The key thing is to make sure that model exactly mirrors the existing table.  If there are small differences you may be able to use `sync_table(MyModel)` to update the table to match your model.